# Persisting information across repeat form submission attempts

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is a simplified version of a sign-up page I'm working on.

When the user clicks the button I need to collect money from a credit card.  Then, if the transaction is successful, create the new user account.

My problem is handling the scenario where the credit card transaction succeeds but then the create-user transaction fails. If the user needs to correct some information in the form I don't want to charge their card again.
My `PaymentStatus` variable contains a `1` or a `0` depending on whether or not the transaction succeeds.

Will this persist across multiple button clicks? And if it does, is this a reliable way of avoiding duplicate transactions in scenarios where the user needs to correct some data in the form?
I could persist the information to the database, but my preference would be to do that later in the transaction when there exists a `UserID` to associate the payment with.

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    int PaymentStatus = ChargeCardForSignUpFee(userInfo);

    if (PaymentStatus == 0)
    {
         Label1.Text = "Your credit card is invalid.  Please try again.";
    }
    else
    {

        try
        {
        MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(userInfo);
            if (newUser == null)
            {
                lblStatus.Text = GetErrorMessage(status);
            }
            else
            {
                CreateCustomer(userInfo);
                SendWelcomeEmail(userInfo.email);
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);

                Response.Redirect("welcomepage.aspx");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "An error occurred while creating your account. "+
                "Please check your information and try again. "+ 
                ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validate the data first, then charge the card. It doesn't make sense to charge the card before validating the data.

Also, save the data to the database before charging the card.

Answer (score 1):

Validate the data first, then charge the card. It doesn't make sense to charge the card before validating the data.

Comment: I do quite a bit of that already.  But I don't think my validation can solve for every possible reason the create-user transaction might fail.  I guess I'm looking for something more bullet proof.

Comment: In the code, it uses a try catch and assumes that the user entered bad data, which means the try catch is actually being used for user form data validation. That is not a best practice. Try catch should be used for exception handling. Incorrectly entered data by a user should be handled by form validation first. Are you using any form validation?

Comment: Just curious, do you really want to show the exception message to the end user? "ex.Message" That could be a huge security hole.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll refactor this to not use the try catch.  I'm using asp.net validation controls to check the user-entered data.  Those controls catch most of the potential issues.  And yes, bad move on my part showing ex.Message to the user.  Need to fix that.

Comment: Glad I could be of some help!